# How do I remove the shade from this ceiling light?

Tags: light-fixture

I am trying to remove the shade of this ceiling light to clean it/replace bulbs, and can't figure out to get it off. The fixture has a large glass dome shade suspended by three wires  from the ceiling plate of the fixture. The wires feed through holes in the dome and are capped off by spherical beads to secure them. I cannot find a way to detach the wires from the ceiling plate, nor any way to unscrew/detach the beads which cap off the wires. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: light fixture]
[[image: interior view of wire-dome attachment2]
[image: view of top attachment]

The two spherical beads on the top plate seem to be unrelated to the wires suspending the dome -- I assume they are caps for the screws holding the fixture to the ceiling.

Comment: remove the spherical beads

Comment: remove the beads on the outside of the shade